# Is there a Windows Command Line utility or DLL to convert URL text to clickable Hyperlinks in PDF files?

Tags: windows, asp-classic, asp, pdf, dll

I'm editing an ASP Classic application that uses a DLL called PDFLib to import existing PDF files, make modifications, and generate new PDF files.

The problem is that any URLs that were in the source PDF are not hyperlinks in the generated PDF. The URLs are all standard base URL http:// format, but it's not a clickable hyperlink in the PDF, it's just plain text.

Is there a Windows Command Line utility or a DLL I can call from the ASP Classic application to convert the text URLs in a PDF file into hyperlink clickable URLs and output a new PDF file (or overwrite the existing file)?